# angularjs 'ng-href' not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a link to each id using angularjs ng-href but when I refresh the page, the links don't show up. I even closed the browser and cleared the cache yet nothing is happening. Here is my current code:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="parcel in parcels">
<td><a ng-href="http://www.proj.com/{{ parcel.id }}/edit/"/>{{ parcel.
 id }}</td>
<td>{{ parcel.tracking_id }}</td>
<td>{{ parcel.shipper_ref_no }}</td>
```

```
$scope.parcels = [];
$scope.scans = [];
$scope.missings = [];
$scope.excludeds = [];

$scope.parcels = Outbound.summaryPageData.parcels;
$scope.scans = Outbound.summaryPageData.scans;
$scope.missings = Outbound.summaryPageData.missings;
$scope.excludeds = Outbound.summaryPageData.excludeds;


 });
```

Comment: How do you know `ng-href` is not working? Maybe the problem is with your `ng-repeat` directive. Please post your controller's code.

Comment: Can we see you javascript? At least the part that works with this snippet.

Comment: I've posted my controller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's a simple HTML syntax error - the `<a>` tag has no content. Try changing this:

```
<a ng-href="http://www.proj.com/{{ parcel.id }}/edit/"/>{{ parcel.id }}
```

to:

```
<a ng-href="http://www.proj.com/{{ parcel.id }}/edit/">{{ parcel.id }}</a>
```

Comment: Yes, this moment is clearly described here:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Comment: Worked. thanks for that. I got my ng-href straight from the angularjs documentation and it wasn't working. Thanks. I'll accept your answer when I can :)

Comment: Well, the way I see it, this has nothing to do with `href` vs `ng-href` at all, but with the fact that `<a>` tags need content to show up in the page (and I think strictly speaking they must not be self closing according to HTML specs). The documentation seems to be a bit misleading here.

Comment: FYI, I already sent a pull request to the AngularJS GitHub project to fix this documentation issue.

Comment: Does it require a full path? Mine looks like `<a ng-href="/page.php#param:{{myparam}}"><span> content here </span></a>` but when I click on it, while it changes the URL in the address bar of the browser correctly (and it's a legitimate URL; I can hit "enter" in the address bar and it will "go there"), it does not actually GO TO that page. Do I need to combine this with an `ng-click` of some sort?  And if so, why?

Comment: @code-sushi: Sorry, I don't have an answer for that. You should ask a new question, because it's a different problem.