# 1.4.3 data-ng-href not changing page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've looked at the following:

[angularjs 'ng-href' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141383/angularjs-ng-href-not-working)

[AngularJS ng-href does not go to link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574063/angularjs-ng-href-does-not-go-to-link)

Following code does not work either:

```
<div data-ng-controller="secureNavCtrl" class="container">
    <a data-ng-href="/signout">sign out</a>
</div>
```

The code above only changes the url in the browser, but does not actually change the page.

```
.controller('secureNavCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$cookies', function ($scope, $window, $location, $cookies) {
    }]);
```

Controller code is empty.

**Does anyone know why this is not working? I don't seem to be the only one with this issue.**

Comment: Could you post a plunker?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ng-href
and ng-controller

without the "data-" prefix.
also have you setted up an ng-app in the begging of the html?

Comment: Wrong. It's good practice as it helps validation of your html. Indeed I have `data-ng-app` at the top! Everything works, just this :/

Comment: I do not have any routes actually. The only thing I'm using angularjs atm is to submit a form.

Comment: and if you go directly to this route, not with ng-href it works?
directly to site.com/signout and refresh